# Flask_SQLAlchemy can't read structure of a table created in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I created a table using SQLAlchemy:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sd.sqlite')

images = Table(
   'images', meta,
   Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True),
   Column('url', String),
   ...
)

meta.create_all(engine)
```

This works, I have a database and can fill it with data. I want to create a Flask application to access this data using Flask_SQLAlchemy, but can't get it to work:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////sd.sqlite'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Base = db.declarative_base()

class Images(db.Model):
    with app.app_context(): #needed to fix application context error
        __table__ = db.Table('images', Base.metadata),

""" with app.app_context():
    db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine) """

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    images = Images.query.all()
    return images

app.run(port=8131)
```

This gives the following error:

> Mapper Mapper[Images(images)] could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'images'

But I specified a primary key. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out there were two issues with my code:

1. I needed to specify the absolute path of my database file. Also, there should only be three slashes after the `sqlite:`
2. I had to use the following syntax to get my tables schema:

```
 Images = db.Table(
         "images", 
         db.Model.metadata,
         autoload_with=db.engine
    )
```

3. I had to use `db.reflect()` instead of the declarative_base